# Using MYSQL GROUP_CONCAT in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate

Is it possible to put GROUP_CONCAT in a MYSQL WHERE clause?

I have two tables (one for members and one for payment info). For example

**Members Table**

```
num, memNumber, fullName, coporateName, surname
001, mem0010, Joe Bloggs, NULL, Bloggs
002, mem0015, NULL, BBC
003, mem0017, John Peters, NULL
004, mem0101, Emma Jane, NULL
```

**Payment Table**

```
num, memberID, subscriptionYear, amount
001, mem0010, 2008, 30
003, mem0010, 2010, 40
004, mem0015, 2010, 40
005, mem0017, 2009, 35
006, mem0101, 2009, 35
007, mem0017, 2010, 40
```

I have the following query to retrieve info from both tables (I have simplified it to make it more readable).

```
SELECT members.num, members.memNumber , members.fullName , members.corporateName ,
       CONCAT(members.corporateName , members.surname) AS searchSurname ,
       GROUP_CONCAT(payment.subscriptionYear) As subscriptionYear ,
       GROUP_CONCAT(payment.amount) AS amount    
FROM members 
LEFT JOIN payment ON members.memNumber = payment.memberID    
WHERE `subscriptionYear` NOT LIKE '%2009%'    
GROUP BY members.num    
ORDER BY `searchSurname` ASC
```

But it removes the "2009" from the results of the `subscriptionYear` column. Can't see if 2009 is in the resultant GROUP_CONCAT?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

WHERE happens BEFORE the grouping, you want to use HAVING, which happens after the grouping.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for being so quick and helpful. Didn't think it would be that easy! For some reason I hadn't come across HAVING.

This now works-
SELECT members.num, members.memNumber, members.fullName, members.corporateName,
CONCAT(members.corporateName , members.surname) AS searchSurname,
GROUP_CONCAT(payment.subscriptionYear) As subscriptionYear,
GROUP_CONCAT(payment.amount) AS amount

FROM members LEFT JOIN payment ON members.memNumber = payment.memberID
WHERE `subscriptionYear` NOT LIKE '%2009%'
GROUP BY members.num
HAVING subscriptionYear NOT LIKE '%2009%' 
ORDER BY `searchSurname` ASC

Comment: Isn't that redundant? If your WHERE is removing 2009 lines before the grouping, no grouping should even have 2009 in it?
Or is it just a case of your example being just an example and not the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

The clause "HAVING" is used when it is necessary to use a filter after a group (GROUP BY, GROUP_COCANT, ...). Instead, the "WHERE" clause creates a filter before the agroupment happens.

You could use the code bellow:

```
SELECT members.num, members.memNumber , members.fullName , members.corporateName ,
       CONCAT(members.corporateName , members.surname) AS searchSurname ,
       GROUP_CONCAT(payment.subscriptionYear) As subscriptionYear ,
       GROUP_CONCAT(payment.amount) AS amount    
FROM members 
LEFT JOIN payment ON members.memNumber = payment.memberID    
HAVING `subscriptionYear` NOT LIKE '%2009%'    
GROUP BY members.num    
ORDER BY `searchSurname` ASC
```

In case, on MYSQL it is not possible to mention a GROUP_CONCAT or a alias on WHERE clause, because WHERE clause happens before it. The HAVING clause also fix this issue.

Comment: `HAVING` has to come after `GROUP BY`, not before it. otherwise, it throws a syntax error. see [MySQL query reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) for more details.

Comment: You're right! I will edit my comment due to it! Thanks for the documentation!